# finding average of numbers using while loop

Tags: c++

I'm new to cpp and want to find the average of exam score using while loop, the number of student attended exam is not clear thats why i used while loop but it doesnt give the right answer.

```
int main() {

    int Average = 0;
    int x=0;
    int counter=0;
    int sum=0;
    
        while (x!=1) {
            cout << "enter a score";
            cin >> x;
             sum += x;
            ++counter;
            Average =  sum / counter;

        }       
}
```

Comment: So what answer _does_ it give? What's your input? What's your expected output? Y'know, the nitty gritty.

Comment: Think about what happens after you enter `1` to end the loop...

Comment: You should divide the sum by the count after you have added up all the numbers, not while you are adding the numbers up.

Comment: average of 10,10,10 and it gives 7

Comment: int main() {

 int Average = 0;
 int x=0;
 int counter=0;
 int sum = 0;
    int  y = 0;
 
 while (x != 1) {
  cout << "enter a score";
  cin >> x;
  sum += x;
  counter++;
  y += counter;

 }
 Average = sum / y;

 cout << Average;
} is it what u mean?

Comment: @AMIRPEDRAM What is the average of 10, 10, 10 and 1?

Comment: I guess 7.75    is not it?

Comment: `7.75` is not an integer, so you cannot store it in `int`. If both arguments to `/` are ints, you will get an `int`. Use `double` if you need fractions.

Comment: This is why our Intro to Programming has an algebra pre-req. Being able to to understand and perform fairly basic math is pretty darn important.

Comment: yeah i solved it the problem is not there , i used double many times but still it was not working as well , thanks btw

Answer (score 2):

You are including the terminating `1` in the values of `sum` and `counter`, which is why you end up with the incorrect `Average` of 7:

10 + 10 + 10 + 1 = 31
31 / 4 = 7

Instead of the expected `Average` of 10:

10 + 10 + 10 = 30
30 / 3 = 10

You need to `break` the loop when `1` is entered, before you update `sum` and `counter`, eg:

```
int main() {

    int Average = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    
    do {
        cout << "enter a score";
        if (!(cin >> x)) break; // <-- add this
        if (x == 1) break; // <-- add this
        sum += x;
        ++counter;
    }       
    while (true);

    if (counter != 0) // <-- add this
        Average =  sum / counter;
}
```